# Please explain that how this Java code identify maximum number from user input?

Tags: java

if a user 8,10,50 why this code only shows 50 why doesn't it show 8,10 as there is condition number > max. 8,10 are also > 0.

```
package com.Zeeshan;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        while (true ) {
            System.out.println("Enter Number");
            boolean isNext = scanner.hasNextInt();

            if (isNext) {
                int NewMax = scanner.nextInt();

                    if (NewMax > max) {
                        max = NewMax;
                    }
                    if (NewMax < min) {
                        min = NewMax;
                    }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

            scanner.nextLine();

        }
        System.out.println("max " + max + "min " + min);

        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: It's only printing the values *at the end of the loop*, once it's determined the minimum and maximum. But it'll show 0 as the minimum at the moment, because no number is less than 0, and `min` starts as 0.

Answer (score 0):

NewMax < min this condition will always false due to min = 0 at beginning. 
You need to take care that your first number must set to min.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code, you should look at the first 2 numbers. You should set min to the lowest of the 2 and max to the highest. From then on, you can compare the next number with min and max.

UPDATE: try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // We assume there are at least 2 input numbers.
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int first = scanner.nextInt();
    int second = scanner.nextInt();
    if (first > second) {
        max = first;
        min = second;
    }
    else {
        max = second;
        min = first;
    }

    while (true ) {
        System.out.println("Enter Number");
        boolean isNext = scanner.hasNextInt();

        if (isNext) {
            int NewMax = scanner.nextInt();

                if (NewMax > max) {
                    max = NewMax;
                }
                if (NewMax < min) {
                    min = NewMax;
                }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

        scanner.nextLine();

    }
    System.out.println("max " + max + "min " + min);

    scanner.close();

}
```